# Core data parent child synchronization

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am having problems with the synchronization between child and parent managed object contexts.

I have two contexts:

1. `mainContext` with `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` as currency type.
2. `childContext` with mainContext as parent and the following configuration: `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` and `NSOverwriteMergePolicyType`

I have also a model that we can call it as `Model`.
I change some properties of all instances of `Model` in `childContext` when I need it:

```
[childContext performBlock:^{
    NSArray *allModels = [self retrieveAllModelsIn:childContext];
    for(Model *model in allModels) {
        [model updateSomeProperties];
    }

    if ([childContext hasChanges]) {
        NSError *error;
        [childContext save:&error];
    }
}];
```

I do the following in `mainContext`:

```
[mainContext performBlock:^{
    NSArray *allModels = [self retrieveAllModelsIn:mainContext];
    for(Model *model in allModels) {
        // Do some stuff with Model
        ...

        // Eventually I need to delete a model
        if (condition) {
            [mainContext deleteObject:model];
        }
    }       
}];
```

Once everything is explained the problem is the following: Sometimes I get an object faultfill when I execute `[model updateSomeProperties]` in `childContext` because while `childContext` is iterating all models (retrieved previously), the `mainContext` may have deleted the object so the model is not valid when I am trying to do something on it on the `childContext`.

My question is: What is the best way or the best practice to avoid this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try refreshing the object before making changes to it: - (void)refreshObject:(NSManagedObject *)object mergeChanges:(BOOL)flag;

Comment: Yes, I can do it but that doesn't resolve the problem.
I think, must be a right way to resolve it.

Comment: So refreshing it doesn't do anything?

Comment: Yes, it refresh the object but the object can be deleted at the moment  or just when the refresh has finished and the problem still exist. Because of that, I think that is only a partial solution, not a definitive solution.

Comment: In that case, the best practice is to have a better design. Don't delete or update an object in one context while trying to do the same in the other.